# How did Counselor Troi trick Tasha Yar?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In the episode Code of Honor, Yar says that Troi tricked her when Deanna appears to read Tasha's emotions to reveal that she is flattered by Lutan's request to make her his First One.

What was the trick?  Since this was a very early episode, was this just to show the audience that Deanna can read minds/emotional states? Was there more to the scene that was cut that made this make more sense? Did Tasha not know about Troi's <s>Jedi mind tricks</s> empathic abilities, and just recognized it for the first time?

> Troi: But it was a thrill.... Lutan is such, such a basic male image.
>   And having him say he wants you....
>
> Yar: Yes of course it made me feel good when he...Troi, I'm your
>   friend and you tricked me!

Are there deleted scenes or statements by the writers/production crew that explain this "trick"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "trick" here is that rather than outright telling Tasha that she's interested in Lutan (which she'll probably deny if it's put to her directly), that Troi uses a verbal trick to *get Tasha to admit it to herself*.

Frankly, you don't need to be an empath to recognise that someone with Tasha's personality is liable to be flattered by the advances of a brute like [Lutan](http://media.agonybooth.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/07035316/Lutan-2-e1471059823580-720x340.jpg).

---

The [original script](http://www.st-minutiae.com/resources/scripts/104.txt) offers us a little more info in the stage direction.

> **PICARD:** *Did you have any idea, Lieutenant, that Lutan would suddenly
>   announce he wanted you for his First One? What do you know of this?*
>
> **TASHA:** *Nothing, sir.*
>
> **TROI:** (as if to herself) *But it was a thrill. Lutan is such... such a basic male image and having him say he wants you...*
>
> **TASHA:** (nods) *Yes, of course it made me feel good...*
>
> Then she becomes aware that Picard is watching this closely. She turns
>   on Troi:
>
> **TASHA:** (continuing) *Troi! I'm your friend and you tricked me!*
>
> **TROI:** *Only so you'll think about it completely and clearly.*

Answer (score 2):

As a half-betazoid/half-human, Troi is empathic, but not telepathic (although it does seem she can engage in telepathy in some circumstances - particularly with other telepaths, but also Riker who she had strong emotional attachments to).

At this very early point in the series, the writers had yet to solidify much of the various characters' traits and abilities - and Troi's empathy was a tricky one: where's the suspense of an alien confrontation if she can turn to Picard and inform him the enemy is vocalising through it's cloaca? (and yeah, she does do this from time to time, in so many words)

Anyway - it seems that they tried to dial the empathy down to surface or strong feelings - meaning that Troi has to probe first either through questions or leading the other person(s) into presenting those emotions. This is the case with the conversation you quote - Troi is quite blatantly leading an unsuspecting Yar who suddenly remembers that Troi is an empath.

Comment: "vocalizing through its cloaca" - I like it!

Comment: She was originally going to have full telepathy, especially in the early days when Yar was still in the picture. They changed because it turns out it ruins a lot of plot holes if someone can read minds every time.